# Active Choices: Single Map backing two single-select dropdowns

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have a set of data that is returned as a single JSON blob that deserializes into a map.  The keys of the map should back one dropdown, and the values of each key are an array of strings that, when that key is chosen in the first dropdown, populate the second dropdown.  Changing the first dropdown should repopulate the second with the new set of values corresponding to the array that is the value of the new key.

```
['foo': ['bar','baz'], 'zoo': ['rab','zab']]
```

The above data should have one dropdown with 'foo' and 'zoo' as choices.  When 'foo' is chosen, the other dropdown should have 'bar' and 'baz'.  If 'zoo' is chosen, the other dropdown should change to 'rab' and 'zab'.

I don't want to make the API call more than once as it's not a cheap call, but I am having trouble figuring out if it's possible to back two controls with a single map... I know that I can use reactive controls to make one change based on the value in another dynamically, but not how to have both looking at one data structure.

Either I'm missing something silly, or it's not possible.  I'm not sure which it is.